# Detecting overloaded method from parent class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

I have been using this utility below to detect if a member method has been defined in a class, which works in most of the cases in my framework.

```
template <typename C, typename TInput>
class HasHandle
{
    template <class T>
    static std::true_type testSignature(void(T::*)(const TInput&));

    template <class T>
    static decltype(testSignature(&T::HandleEvent)) test(std::nullptr_t);

    template <class T>
    static std::false_type                          test(...);

public:
    using type = decltype(test<C>(nullptr));
    static constexpr bool value = type::value;
};
```

But the problem happens when I try to move some shared `EventHandle` into the base class, so I can share the same event handling logic in multiple classes.

After moving some `EventHandle` into the base class and uses `using EventHandle` to make the base class method visible, I noticed `HasHandle` will fail to detect the `EventHandle` I defined in the base class.

Here is a quick example:

```
struct ShareEventHandler
{
    void HandleEvent(const int&) {}
};

struct Foo : public ShareEventHandler
{
    using ShareEventHandler::HandleEvent;
    void HandleEvent(const Foo&) {}
};

static_assert(HasHandle<Foo, Foo>::value, "failed to detect the method");
static_assert(HasHandle<Foo, int>::value, "failed to detect the method"); // this will fail
```

Does anyone have an idea about how to improve `HasHandle` to resolve the failed static_assert above?

---

Update :
I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.1, according to the comment, the issue can't be reproduced on g++ 8.3.0 and clang++ 7.0.1
Here is a link for the compile test.
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1x9n3Y

Comment: Cannot reproduce: no failure from g++ 8.3.0 or from clang++ 7.0.1. Please, can you show a full reproducible example? For full I mean also the include files you use, a `main()` function (if needed), the version of your compiler and the compiler options

Comment: @max66 I am using Visual Studio compiler. (Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.1)
And this is the compile command 
CL.exe /c /ZI /JMC /nologo /W4 /WX- /diagnostics:column /sdl /Od /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _DEBUG /D _CONSOLE /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /permissive- /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /std:c++latest /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /FC /errorReport:prompt teslapp.cpp
Seems like it's a compiler related issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing template for `testSignature` makes all compilers happy:

```
template <typename C, typename TInput>
class HasHandle
{
    static std::true_type testSignature(void(C::*)(const TInput&));

    template <class T>
    static decltype(testSignature(&T::HandleEvent)) test(std::nullptr_t);

    template <class T>
    static std::false_type                          test(...);

public:
    using type = decltype(test<C>(nullptr));
    static constexpr bool value = type::value;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3jxc3x)